# toggle function not working when user click on product-box

Tags: jquery, html, css

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('.subBox').click(function(e) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
  if($(this).hasClass('active'))
  {
   $(this).find('.addtocart').addClass('active addedtocart').html('<i class="carticon"></i>Added to Cart');
  }
  else
  {
   //$(this).removeClass('active');
   $(this).find('.addtocart').removeClass('active addedtocart').html('<i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart');
   //$(this).next('.addtocart').removeClass('active');
   //$(this).next('.addtocart').removeClass('addedtocart');
   //$(this).next('.addtocart').html('<i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart');
  }
    });
 $('#entire-grp-btn').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('');
    });
});
```

```css
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
body{font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif !important; font-size:14px !important;}
.PL0{padding-left:0px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.FL{float:left;}
.FR{float:right;}
.CL{clear:both;}
.DN{display:none;}
.PT20{padding-top:20px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.DIB{display:inline-block;}
.TAC{text-align:center;}
.MB10{margin-bottom:10px;}
.MT3{margin-top:3px;}
.MT7{margin-top:7px;}
.MT5{margin-top:5px;}
.MT10{margin-top:10px;}
.PLR20{padding:0px 20px;}
.PT10{padding-top:10px;}
.clearfix{display:block;}
.CTR{text-align: center;}
.disN{display:none;}
.FL{float:left;}
.FR{float:right;}
.PR,.highlight{ position: relative;}
.CL{clear:both;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;}
.clearfix:after{height: 0;clear: both;}
.clearfix{display: block;}
.DN{display:none;}
.DIB{display:inline-block;}
.DB{display:block;}
.TAC{text-align:center;}

.MT-8{margin-top: -8px;}
.MT3{margin-top: 3px;}
.MT5{margin-top: 5px;}
.MT7{margin-top: 7px;}
.MT12{margin-top: 12px;}
.MT10{margin-top: 10px;}
.MT15{margin-top:15px;}
.MT20{margin-top:20px;}
.ML15{margin-left: 15px;}
.MT15{margin-top: 15px;}
.ML10{margin-left: 10px;}
.ML20{margin-left: 20px;}
.MB10{margin-bottom:10px;}
.MB15{margin-bottom: 15px;}
.MR3{margin-right: 3px;}
.MR8{margin-right:8px;}
.MR10{margin-right: 10px;}
.MR20{margin-right:20px;}

.PA5{padding: 5px;}
.PA15{padding: 15px;}
.PA20{padding: 20px;}
.PT7{padding-top: 7px;}
.PT10{padding-top: 10px;}
.PT20{padding-top:20px;}
.PT30{padding-top: 30px;}
.PB15{padding-bottom: 15px;}
.PB10{padding-bottom:10px;}
.PB20{padding-bottom: 20px;}
.PB30{padding-bottom: 30px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.PR5{padding-right: 5px;}
.PR10{padding-right:10px;}
.PR12{padding-right: 12px;}
.PR20{padding:0px 20px;}
.PL0{padding-left:0px;}
.PL5{padding-left: 5px;}
.PL10{padding-left:10px;}
.PL12{padding-left:12px;} 

@font-face{font-family: 'WebRupee'; src: url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.eot'); src: local('WebRupee'), url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.ttf') format('truetype'),  url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
.rupee{font-family:'WebRupee';font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:500;}
.rupee20{font-family:'WebRupee';font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;}

.courseslink{list-style:none; display:block; padding:15px 0px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center;}
.courseslink li{display:inline-block; padding:0px 40px;  border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
.courseslink li:last-child{border-right:0px;}
.courseslink li a{font:500 14px/16px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#0081cd; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 10px;}
.courseslink li a:hover{background:#0081cd; border-radius:3px; color:#fff;}
.courseMainHdg{font:600 20px/26px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#666; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:10px 0px;}

#exTab .nav-pills{border-bottom:5px solid #02356a;}
#exTab .nav-pills> li{margin-left:0px !important;}
#exTab .nav-pills > li > a{border-radius: 0; cursor:pointer;}
#exTab .nav-pills> #exTab li>a, #exTab .nav-pills>li>a:focus, #exTab .nav-pills>li>a:hover{color: #fff; background: #02356a;}
#exTab .nav-pills> li.active>a, #exTab .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, #exTab .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover{color: #fff; background: #02356a;}
#exTab .tab-content{color : #666; background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ccc; border-top:0px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:15px; display:block !important;}

.single-Box{background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin-bottom:15px;}

.subcontainer{margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; display:block;}
.subcontainer li{display:inline-block; padding:5px 12px 5px 0px; vertical-align:top;}
.subcontainer li .subBox{width:270px; background:#FFF; cursor:pointer;}
.subcontainer li .subBox .active{border:2px solid #0081cd; border-top:0px;}
.subcontainer li .subBox:hover{box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.subcontainer li .subBox:hover .subDetails{border:2px solid #0081cd; border-top:0px;}

.subcontainer li .subBox h3{background:#0081cd; color:#fff; font:600 20px/20px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:15px 0px;}
.subDetails{display:block; border:2px solid #e5e5e5; border-top:0px;} /*8border:3px solid #0081cd; e4f5ff*/
.subDetails > ul{ list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; display:block;}
.subDetails > ul li{display:block; padding:7px 15px; background:#F0f0f0; border-bottom:1px solid #d5d4d4;}
.subDetails .coursetime{background:#edecec; border-bottom:1px solid #d5d4d4; font:400 15px/20px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#02356a; text-align:center; display:block; margin:0px !important; padding:14px 0px !important;}
.subDetails .coursetime strong{font-weight:900;}
.subDetails > ul li .rightIcon{display:inline-block;background:url(http://cdn.topperlearning.com/topper/img/checked_icon.png) no-repeat; width: 16px;height: 16px; padding-top:5px; position:relative; margin:2px 10px 0px 5px; text-align: center;float:left;}
.subPrice{font:900 28px/30px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#02356a;text-align:center; display:block; padding:8px 0px 5px; display:block;}
/*single product Add to Cart Button*/

.carticon{background:url(images/cart_icon_2.png) no-repeat;display:inline-block; width:20px;height:20px; padding-top:5px; position:absolute; margin:0px 0px 0px -25px; text-align: center; outline:none; text-align:none;}
.addtocart:focus,.addtocart:active,.addtocart:hover{text-decoration:none; outline:none; box-shadow:none; border:0px !important;}
.addtocart{background:#f58000; border-radius:3px; width:243px; text-align:center; font:600 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px 0px; box-shadow:none; border:0px !important; margin:0 auto; text-transform:uppercase;padding-left:25px; position:relative;}
/*single product Add to Cart Button*/

/*single product Added to Cart Button*/
.addedtocart{background:#b16a01; border-radius:3px; width:243px; text-align:center; font:600 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px 0px; box-shadow:none; border:0px; margin:0 auto; text-transform:uppercase;padding-left:25px; position:relative;}

.dsc-offer{background:#edecec; padding:5px 0px; border-top:1px dashed #ccc;}
.dsc-offer .discount-txt{color:#00c032; text-align:center; font:600 22px/24px 'Lato',Arial, sans-serif; display:block;}
.dsc-offer > p{margin:0px; padding:0px 5px; color:#666; text-align:center; font:500 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial, sans-serif; } 

/*Entire Group Box*/
.entire-group .coursetime,.entire-group li{background:#e4f5ff !important;}
.entire-group .addtocart{background:#02356a !important;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.courseslink li{padding:0px 5px;}
.courseslink li a{padding:5px;}
.subcontainer{display:flex;}
.tab-content{overflow-x:scroll;}
#exTab .tab-conten{overflow-x:scroll;}
/*.tab-content-store{ overflow-x:scroll;}*/
}
@media only screen and (device-width: 414px), (device-width: 412px) , (device-width: 375px) , (device-width: 360px) , (device-width: 320px){
.courseslink li{padding: 0px 0px;}
.courseslink li a{padding:5px 2px;}
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 320px){
.subcontainer li .subBox{width: 255px;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid section5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="courseMainHdg" id="ca-cpt">CA CPT</h2>
            <div id="exTab"> 
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-target="#cacptg1" data-toggle="tab">Group 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#cacptg2" data-toggle="tab">Group 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="cacptg1">
                     <ul class="subcontainer">
                         <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Accounting</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i><span class="carttext">Add to Cart</span></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dsc-offer">
                                         <span class="discount-txt">10% discount</span>
                                            <p>on purchesing <strong>Ethics & Communication</strong></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Law</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Ethics & Communication</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Costing</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Financial Management</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Direct Tax</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Indirect Tax</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox entire-group">
                                 <h3>Entire Group I</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart" id="entire-grp-btn"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="cacptg2">
                     <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Requirement:
When user click on product-box, the "Add to cart" button need to be change as "Added to cart" and box will be applied blue border as an selected product.
and again reverse of it on deselection.

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzypG.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are always adding `active` class and directly after checking if element has this class.

First check, only than add/remove

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 $('.subBox').click(function(e) {
   var btn = $(this).find('.addtocart');
    
  if(!btn.hasClass('active'))
  {
   btn.addClass('active addedtocart').html('<i class="carticon"></i>Added to Cart');
  }
  else
  {
   btn.removeClass('active addedtocart').html('<i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart');
  }
    });
 $('#entire-grp-btn').click(function(e) {
        $(this).toggleClass('');
    });
});
```

```css
*{margin:0px; padding:0px;}
body{font-family:'Lato', Arial, sans-serif !important; font-size:14px !important;}
.PL0{padding-left:0px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.FL{float:left;}
.FR{float:right;}
.CL{clear:both;}
.DN{display:none;}
.PT20{padding-top:20px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.DIB{display:inline-block;}
.TAC{text-align:center;}
.MB10{margin-bottom:10px;}
.MT3{margin-top:3px;}
.MT7{margin-top:7px;}
.MT5{margin-top:5px;}
.MT10{margin-top:10px;}
.PLR20{padding:0px 20px;}
.PT10{padding-top:10px;}
.clearfix{display:block;}
.CTR{text-align: center;}
.disN{display:none;}
.FL{float:left;}
.FR{float:right;}
.PR,.highlight{ position: relative;}
.CL{clear:both;font-size: 0;line-height: 0;}
.clearfix:after{height: 0;clear: both;}
.clearfix{display: block;}
.DN{display:none;}
.DIB{display:inline-block;}
.DB{display:block;}
.TAC{text-align:center;}

.MT-8{margin-top: -8px;}
.MT3{margin-top: 3px;}
.MT5{margin-top: 5px;}
.MT7{margin-top: 7px;}
.MT12{margin-top: 12px;}
.MT10{margin-top: 10px;}
.MT15{margin-top:15px;}
.MT20{margin-top:20px;}
.ML15{margin-left: 15px;}
.MT15{margin-top: 15px;}
.ML10{margin-left: 10px;}
.ML20{margin-left: 20px;}
.MB10{margin-bottom:10px;}
.MB15{margin-bottom: 15px;}
.MR3{margin-right: 3px;}
.MR8{margin-right:8px;}
.MR10{margin-right: 10px;}
.MR20{margin-right:20px;}

.PA5{padding: 5px;}
.PA15{padding: 15px;}
.PA20{padding: 20px;}
.PT7{padding-top: 7px;}
.PT10{padding-top: 10px;}
.PT20{padding-top:20px;}
.PT30{padding-top: 30px;}
.PB15{padding-bottom: 15px;}
.PB10{padding-bottom:10px;}
.PB20{padding-bottom: 20px;}
.PB30{padding-bottom: 30px;}
.PR0{padding-right:0px;}
.PR5{padding-right: 5px;}
.PR10{padding-right:10px;}
.PR12{padding-right: 12px;}
.PR20{padding:0px 20px;}
.PL0{padding-left:0px;}
.PL5{padding-left: 5px;}
.PL10{padding-left:10px;}
.PL12{padding-left:12px;} 

@font-face{font-family: 'WebRupee'; src: url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.eot'); src: local('WebRupee'), url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.ttf') format('truetype'),  url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/WebRupee.V2.0.svg') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;}
.rupee{font-family:'WebRupee';font-size:12px;font-style:normal;font-weight:500;}
.rupee20{font-family:'WebRupee';font-size:20px;font-style:normal;font-weight:600;}

.courseslink{list-style:none; display:block; padding:15px 0px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc; text-align:center;}
.courseslink li{display:inline-block; padding:0px 40px;  border-right:1px solid #ccc;}
.courseslink li:last-child{border-right:0px;}
.courseslink li a{font:500 14px/16px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#0081cd; text-decoration:none; padding:5px 10px;}
.courseslink li a:hover{background:#0081cd; border-radius:3px; color:#fff;}
.courseMainHdg{font:600 20px/26px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#666; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:10px 0px;}

#exTab .nav-pills{border-bottom:5px solid #02356a;}
#exTab .nav-pills> li{margin-left:0px !important;}
#exTab .nav-pills > li > a{border-radius: 0; cursor:pointer;}
#exTab .nav-pills> #exTab li>a, #exTab .nav-pills>li>a:focus, #exTab .nav-pills>li>a:hover{color: #fff; background: #02356a;}
#exTab .nav-pills> li.active>a, #exTab .nav-pills>li.active>a:focus, #exTab .nav-pills>li.active>a:hover{color: #fff; background: #02356a;}
#exTab .tab-content{color : #666; background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ccc; border-top:0px; padding:10px; margin-bottom:15px; display:block !important;}

.single-Box{background:#FFF; border:1px solid #ccc; padding:10px; margin-bottom:15px;}

.subcontainer{margin:0px; padding:0px; list-style:none; display:block;}
.subcontainer li{display:inline-block; padding:5px 12px 5px 0px; vertical-align:top;}
.subcontainer li .subBox{width:270px; background:#FFF; cursor:pointer;}
.subcontainer li .subBox .active{border:2px solid #0081cd; border-top:0px;}
.subcontainer li .subBox:hover{box-shadow:0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}
.subcontainer li .subBox:hover .subDetails{border:2px solid #0081cd; border-top:0px;}

.subcontainer li .subBox h3{background:#0081cd; color:#fff; font:600 20px/20px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; text-align:center; margin:0px; padding:15px 0px;}
.subDetails{display:block; border:2px solid #e5e5e5; border-top:0px;} /*8border:3px solid #0081cd; e4f5ff*/
.subDetails > ul{ list-style:none; margin:0px; padding:0px; display:block;}
.subDetails > ul li{display:block; padding:7px 15px; background:#F0f0f0; border-bottom:1px solid #d5d4d4;}
.subDetails .coursetime{background:#edecec; border-bottom:1px solid #d5d4d4; font:400 15px/20px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#02356a; text-align:center; display:block; margin:0px !important; padding:14px 0px !important;}
.subDetails .coursetime strong{font-weight:900;}
.subDetails > ul li .rightIcon{display:inline-block;background:url(http://cdn.topperlearning.com/topper/img/checked_icon.png) no-repeat; width: 16px;height: 16px; padding-top:5px; position:relative; margin:2px 10px 0px 5px; text-align: center;float:left;}
.subPrice{font:900 28px/30px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#02356a;text-align:center; display:block; padding:8px 0px 5px; display:block;}
/*single product Add to Cart Button*/

.carticon{background:url(images/cart_icon_2.png) no-repeat;display:inline-block; width:20px;height:20px; padding-top:5px; position:absolute; margin:0px 0px 0px -25px; text-align: center; outline:none; text-align:none;}
.addtocart:focus,.addtocart:active,.addtocart:hover{text-decoration:none; outline:none; box-shadow:none; border:0px !important;}
.addtocart{background:#f58000; border-radius:3px; width:243px; text-align:center; font:600 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px 0px; box-shadow:none; border:0px !important; margin:0 auto; text-transform:uppercase;padding-left:25px; position:relative;}
/*single product Add to Cart Button*/

/*single product Added to Cart Button*/
.addedtocart{background:#b16a01; border-radius:3px; width:243px; text-align:center; font:600 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial,sans-serif; color:#fff; padding:10px 0px; box-shadow:none; border:0px; margin:0 auto; text-transform:uppercase;padding-left:25px; position:relative;}

.dsc-offer{background:#edecec; padding:5px 0px; border-top:1px dashed #ccc;}
.dsc-offer .discount-txt{color:#00c032; text-align:center; font:600 22px/24px 'Lato',Arial, sans-serif; display:block;}
.dsc-offer > p{margin:0px; padding:0px 5px; color:#666; text-align:center; font:500 14px/18px 'Lato',Arial, sans-serif; } 

/*Entire Group Box*/
.entire-group .coursetime,.entire-group li{background:#e4f5ff !important;}
.entire-group .addtocart{background:#02356a !important;}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.courseslink li{padding:0px 5px;}
.courseslink li a{padding:5px;}
.subcontainer{display:flex;}
.tab-content{overflow-x:scroll;}
#exTab .tab-conten{overflow-x:scroll;}
/*.tab-content-store{ overflow-x:scroll;}*/
}
@media only screen and (device-width: 414px), (device-width: 412px) , (device-width: 375px) , (device-width: 360px) , (device-width: 320px){
.courseslink li{padding: 0px 0px;}
.courseslink li a{padding:5px 2px;}
}

@media only screen and (device-width: 320px){
.subcontainer li .subBox{width: 255px;}
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid section5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
            <h2 class="courseMainHdg" id="ca-cpt">CA CPT</h2>
            <div id="exTab"> 
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a data-target="#cacptg1" data-toggle="tab">Group 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a data-target="#cacptg2" data-toggle="tab">Group 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="tab-content clearfix">
                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="cacptg1">
                     <ul class="subcontainer">
                         <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Accounting</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i><span class="carttext">Add to Cart</span></button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="dsc-offer">
                                         <span class="discount-txt">10% discount</span>
                                            <p>on purchesing <strong>Ethics & Communication</strong></p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Law</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Ethics & Communication</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Costing</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Financial Management</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Direct Tax</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox">
                                 <h3>Indirect Tax</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                             <div class="subBox entire-group">
                                 <h3>Entire Group I</h3>
                                    <div class="subDetails">
                                     <h4 class="coursetime">Online Streaming Approx Hrs. <strong>134</strong></h4>
                                     <ul>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Live Doubt Session</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Previous Year Question Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Recorded Version</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Sample Papers</li>
                                            <li><i class="rightIcon"></i> Textbook Solutions</li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <div class="subPrice"><span class="rupee20">₹</span>8499</div>
                                        <div class="TAC MB10">
                                         <button onClick="javascript:void(0);" class="addtocart" id="entire-grp-btn"><i class="carticon"></i>Add to Cart</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="tab-pane" id="cacptg2">
                     <h3>We use the class nav-pills instead of nav-tabs which automatically creates a background color for the tab</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much dear, its working now, thanks for giving the solution with description.